# How to fix Vite manifest not found at: /app/public/build/manifest.json?

Tags: php, laravel, vite

It works locally just fine, but as I deploy it to a host, this popped up, not sure what to look or what to do.

[image]

Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: this tutorial is more helpful: [Vite manifest not found at: manifest.json in Laravel 9](https://devnote.in/vite-manifest-not-found-at-manifest-json-in-laravel-9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest running `npm install && npm run dev` as this seems like a default laravel app.

This would generate the correct files for local development.

If you want to run this in production you should run `npm run prod` somewhere in your build pipeline.

Comment: Its not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the

```bash
npm run build
```

command did the work.